# Filepicker convert shows completely different image

Tags: filepicker.io

In some cases not using [convert](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/v0/#fpurl-images) in the url occasionally shows to a *completely* different image.
The following share the same base-url:

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/8d3kyEaTOKD2NzgqeInQ/convert?fit=clip&h=150&w=150

[image: A picture of a kitten]

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/8d3kyEaTOKD2NzgqeInQ

[image: A completely different picture of a kitten]

#### As you can see, these images are completely different.

Why is this happening, and is there a solution to control this (should I always be using convert)?

*(I suspect it has something to do with metadata from where the images were originally taken from [placekittens](http://placekitten.com/)... but this suggests that other uploaded images could have the same issue.)*

Comment: Update: the second image is now a different one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is honestly one of the strangest issues I've seen - the filepicker.io url is backed by the url client, with the base image being http://placekitten.com/150/150. Somehow that url is returning different images, perhaps based on the user agent, requesting IP, caching layers or a number of other parameters.

One recommendation would be to use the filepicker.pickAndStore() command to ensure that you are working with a snapshot of the data rather than a pointer to the original file itself.

Comment: Interestingly the second image has now changed (to another cat). I think pickAndStore is probably the way to go here, I didn't realise it was by default a snapshot when "uploading" a url.

Answer (score 0):

A (not very satisfying) solution is to always convert to `format=jpg` when displaying the fullsize image:

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/8d3kyEaTOKD2NzgqeInQ/convert?format=jpg

[image: https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/8d3kyEaTOKD2NzgqeInQ/convert?format=jpg]